# Django: Remove trailing zeros for a Django model field

Tags: python, django

I'm trailing to get rid of the unwanted trailing zeros for my Django model field:

```
class mycls(BaseModel):
    price = models.DecimalField()
```

I've even tried to creat a new field.
Here is the Django field I created:

```
class CurrencyField(models.DecimalField):
    INTEGER_PLACES = 15
    DECIMAL_PLACES = 18

    DECIMAL_PLACES_FOR_USER = 6

    MAX_DIGITS = INTEGER_PLACES + DECIMAL_PLACES

    MAX_VALUE = Decimal('999999999999999.999999999999999999')
    MIN_VALUE = Decimal('-999999999999999.999999999999999999')

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, max_digits=MAX_DIGITS,
                 decimal_places=DECIMAL_PLACES, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(verbose_name=verbose_name, name=name, max_digits=max_digits,
                         decimal_places=decimal_places, **kwargs)
```

By using this function I want to remove the trailing from this field

```
def normalize_fraction(d):
    normalized = d.normalize()
    sign, digit, exponent = normalized.as_tuple()
    return normalized if exponent <= 0 else normalized.quantize(1)
```

How can I use this function inside that field class to remove the trailing zeros?

- I want to do that from the model level not from templates or views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override [from_db_value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.from_db_value), try something like this:

```py
class CurrencyField(models.DecimalField):
    ...
    ...
    ...
    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return normalize_fraction(value)
```

Comment: I still have trailing zeros and I guess that's because of the DECIMAL_PLACES. Any solution to it?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the django docs. The correct method to override should be `from_db_value`.

Comment: Why `to_representation` why wrong? Regarding `from_db_value`, where do I have to send the field name?